# How to initialize an array of objects with a shared pointer

Tags: arrays, c++11, shared-ptr

I am tryind to do something like this

```
struct car
{
    car(int a) : name(a) {}
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<car[]>> mp;

    auto t = std::shared_ptr<car[]>(new car[100]); // Error car requires a paremeter.
}
```

My question is how do I pass 1 to every constructor?
The following does not work

```
auto t = std::shared_ptr<car[]>(new car[100](1));
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with `shared_ptr`, you'd have the same issue with a plain `car cars[100];`. `new car[100]{1, 1, ...}` (`1` repeated 100 times) is the only way I know of. Or, give `car` a default constructor (a constructor with no parameters) that sets `val` to 1. Or use `std::vector<car>` in place of `car` array, then you can write `std::vector<car>(100, car(1))`

Comment: Since C++ 20, you can write `std::make_shared<car[]>(100, car(1))` . Not available in C++11.